# How to accomplish this animated piano visual effect in a Livestream?

Tags: animation, youtube, visual-effects, music, video-game

I would like to know how to produce this effect, for example on 1. YouTube Livestream, 2. Zoom, or 3. Omegle meetings. Thank you for your **thoughtful answers/comments** in advance!

See this video:

1. One is the spot with the piano in his own room:

[image]

[image]

2. Another is like Synthesiagame https://synthesiagame.com/ on the screen during the Omegle meeting:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

2. This is simply produce with a synthesia like software. (For example: https://www.piano-vfx.com/   ) Just record a MIDI-File and put some effects on it with this software.
3. For the first one: I can imagine that he makes a video like in 2., but rotates the whole video for a specific angle. Then he puts his piano right next to the camera so it is the same angle as the already rotated video. After, he puts everything together into one video. That means, the particles doesn't even exist in real life but only on screen.

Comment: thanks for this! +1

Answer (score 1):

Both are incorrect. For live capturing you can use something like this:

1. Use any audio visualizer (with a solid background) and add some
   visual effects;
2. Chroma key/mask the background of the visualiser output, similar to how they do with greenscreen;
3. Set up your camera at a fixed position;
4. Overlay and skew the footage to the correct (fixed) camera angle on
   top of the live feed with a virtual camera feed (through OBSe.g.)
5. Go to Omegle or any other site and select your virtual feed as the
   camera input instead of the actual camera feed. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Except it does happen in real-time due to people reacting about the lights and asking how the lights are levitating.

Possibly using a green screen hanging above the piano. If he can animate the lights on his synthesia videos, pretty sure he can just put it on a green screen at that point lol